# PostGIS: register a "geometry" column without AddGeometryColumn

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, geography

The usual way to create a geometry column is **AddGeometryColumn**, however I have to work with pre-existing columns, so I can't use that function (as far as I know).

Thanks to the [PostGIS docs](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_usage.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column), I can already register the column in the "**geometry_columns**" table, however *AddGeometryColumn* seems to do more than **create a column** and **add a row in geometry_columns**, for example it adds **checks** on the column.

---

So my question is what: what do I need to do to register the column manually, besides adding a row in *geometry_columns* ?

(for example, is there a modified version *AddGeometryColumn* that works with an existing column ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of doing it on existing columns is using the function Populate_Geometry_Columns:
https://postgis.net/docs/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html

In other words: The function you are asking for is already there :-)

HTH
Nicklas

Comment: Good suggestion, however I wish it would apply itself only to a specific column instead of a whole table. But it's definitely safer in regards to upgrades than making a modified version of AddGeometryColumn, thanks.

Comment: It is a plpgsql function so maybe you can modify it in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `AddGeometryColumn` is only a handy shortcut for creating not only the column, but adding type checks and indexes. Of course, you can add these by hand to an existing column: you simply need to do the same things that the `AddGeometryColumn` does for you in a single command.

If you need to transfer one "regular" column to a "gis" column, why not use `SELECT INTO` for transfering the data?